# Operation on specific part of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

I am new to MATLAB and I have a question which I think should have an easy solution.However, I am stuck now.

My program produces a vector as a result which contains positive and negative values.
I wish to find a solution that I could assign only positive values of the vector to a new vector and replace the negative values with 0. Of course the size of the vectors should be the same.

The vector size is 1*345600

Pbat(t)   ...... (has both negative and positive numbers)

Pbat1(t)  ...... (should have the same size as Pbat(t) while changing negative values to 0)

Thanks in advance,
Hamed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, using logical indexing...

```
initial_vector = rand(1,345600);
new_vector = initial_vector;
new_vector(initial_vector<0)=0;
```

Comment: More on logical indexing at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1

Comment: Thank you very much :) really easy and helpful.
Sorry I have not enough reputation to vote for you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `max(..., 0)`:

```
initial_vector = randn(1,345600); %// example data 
new_vector = max(initial_vector, 0); %// set negative values to 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear Luis
Sorry I have not enough reputation to vote for you.